# Adding entity to DbContext not possible

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to copy an entity from one `DbContext` to another.
So I'm loading and detaching the entity before calling the save methods of  the other `DbContext`.

**EDIT:**

First of all I'm loading the entity with the ID of the `UserDT`, then I'm detaching it from the old `DbContext`.
Finally I'l set `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tUsers ON`, save the entity and then turn `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tUsers OFF`.

```
var userEntity = DataContext.GetById<User>(id);
DataContext.EnsureDetached(userEntity);
offlineContext.ToggleIdentityInsert(true, typeof(User));
offlineContext.SetSaved(userEntity);
offlineContext.SaveChanges();
offlineContext.ToggleIdentityInsert(false, typeof(User));
```

Before `DbContext.SaveChanges()` I call this method (please note that this method is in a class inheriting from `DbContext`):

```
public T SetSaved<T>(T obj) where T : class, IEntity
{
    var isNew = base.Set<T>().All(t => t.Id != obj.Id);
    T ret = default(T);
    var entry = Entry(obj);
    if (isNew)
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Added;
        ret = base.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

All entities I've used so far worked with this method.

Our `User` entity causes a NullReferenceException when calling this method, because the the properties `CurrentValues` and `OriginalValues` throw an `InvalidOperationException` saying that the entity is not attached to the current `DbContext`.

With this problem I can access the `State` and then add the `obj` to the `DbContex`.

**EDIT:**

I've forgot to say that the above code works on the second try. In my scenario I'm pressing the login button and the logged in user should be copied (offline DB). The first time I'll get the error, the second time I press the login button everything works fine.

Do you know what I could have forgotten?

Comment: Have you tried Attaching it to the context? If it is a new entity you should set the Id property to null before adding it. Also please note that default(T) will return null in your second clause.

Comment: The problem is that attaching the entity to the new `DbContext` doesn't work. And as I'm copying the entities to an other `DbContext` I'm using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON`.

Comment: Also I've forgot to say that the above code works on the second try. In my scenario I'm pressing the login button and the logged in user should be copied (offline DB). The first time I'll get the error, the second time I press the login button everything works fine.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet then? Like, have you disabled proxy generation? You could also use AsNoTracking() to query for a detached entity from your first context.

Comment: I've added some additional code.

Comment: You left out the rather important code that is in your methods though.